# How get an unique identifier for my custom eclipse plugin installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and for statistical purposes I need an unique identifier for that specific installation. I am not very familiar with the Eclipse Plugin SDK so I don't know if it is possible to create an UUID and save it in eclipse workspace or if there is a way to persist data and retrieve it when eclipse is started.

In IntelliJ Platform SDK I can achive that using `DeviceIdManager.getOrGenerateId()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getStateLocation(bundle)` returns a location in the .metadata where your plug-in can store whatever it likes.

Comment: No, the Eclipse community decided against it. [Read this blog post](https://blogs.eclipse.org/post/ian-skerrett/uuid-removal-neon) and consider the same. Please note that there are countries where the user must explicitly consent to this, which bothers most.

Comment: I completely agree with the decision, but unfortunely this is not a personal project and the plugin will be used internaly on my work so I must figure out how to do it =(